# Multiple strokes on live text in InDesign CC

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, stroke

Is there any way to put multiple strokes on live text in InDesign CC that is similar to using the attributes panel in Illustrator?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know NO.

But you could do sort of second stroke with dropshadow set to zero blur.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hacky way you can achieve this.

1. Give your text a stroke
2. Now, select your text box and click `Object > Effects > Inner Glow`

   - Make sure your effect is applied to `Object` in the 'Settings for' drop-down menu
   - Change the 'Blending mode' to `Normal`
   - Select your stroke colour
   - Set 'Opacity' to `100%`
   - Set 'Source' to `Edge`
   - Adjust the 'Size' to the desired thickness
   - Set 'Choke' to `100%`

Using inner and outer glows applied to the `Object` and `Text` elements of your text box, you can add any number of different combinations of 'strokes' to your text.